# Deploying app with sunspot based search on webbyapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, full-text-search, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am trying to deploy a rails app on webbyapp. I am using sunspot for search functionality. It works fine in development mode.

After deploying my app I get the "we are sorry something went wrong" page. I tried to check the logs and got this :-

```
(eval):2:in `post'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:38:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:329:in `solr_execute_search'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:153:in `solr_search'
/var/rapp/StudyAbroader/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:24:in `search'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:24:in `search'
```

I dont know what to make of it.

I installed topcat6 and opnjdk-6 on my production machine as it was told in lot of tutorial.

Here is my sunspot.yml file :-

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: xxx.webbyapp.com
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
```

Updated with netstat-ntpl output

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53888         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8982                 :::*                    LISTEN      19270/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I am trying to debug it since morning but no luck. Can someone please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the schema.xml file in the production with the schema.xml file in development which can be found here appname/solr/conf/schema.xml did it for me, atleast sunspot started to show the search result.